# Getting AccessDenied Error Trying to Get Wildcard SSL with Certbot and Route53 Plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, certbot

I have been tasked with setting up Wilcard SSL for some domains. These domains are hosted through AWS Route53.

I am using **Certbot** on an **Ubuntu 20.4** machine, where the apps are hosted. I have also installed the Route53 DNS plugin for Certbot.

I run this command:

```
sudo certbot certonly --dns-route53 --email 'me@derp.com' --domain 'mywebsite.rocks' --domain '*.mywebsite.rocks' --agree-tos --non-interactive
```

*Real domains remove for security reasons*

I get this error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListHostedZones operation: User: arn:aws:sts::789148085273:assumed-role/AmazonLightsailInstanceRole/i-0871f2572906140c4 is not authorized to perform: route53:ListHostedZones because no identity-based policy allows the route53:ListHostedZones action
```

Let me explain first how I set up the IAM user in the AWS console.

1. I created a new Policy with this config

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "derp0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:GetHostedZone",
                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets",
                "route53:ListResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/WHAT-EVER-MY-ID-IS-HERE"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "derp1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "route53:ListHostedZones",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

*Replacing `WHAT-EVER-MY-ID-IS-HERE` with my actual domain's Hosted Zone ID*

2. I then created a new **IAM User** and during set-up, I attached the above Policy to the user.
3. I then created an **Access Key** for my new User and took note of the `AccessKeyId` and `SecretAccessKey`. This has access to be used programmatically.
4. On the server, I created a config file at `/root/.aws/config` as instructed in the documentation. *I also tried `~/.aws/config`* but as I am using `sudo` the former seemed the preferred location (I could be wrong though, and during my tests, neither worked anyway)

And as previously aforementioned, I run the command and get the error.

Searched the web high and low for a solution, but cannot find one.

Appreciate any help I can get from folk.

Comment: Did something help, I am stuck at the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

What you'll have to do is click on 'Roles' link under 'Access Management':
[image]

Then search for the 'role' that is causing the error because it has insufficient permissions so in your case, your error message indicates that it's the 'AmazonLightsailInstanceRole'. Once you find that role, attach a policy that has the permission 'route53:ListHostedZones'. Not sure why your error message is showing an 'assumed-role' for 'AmazonLightsailInstanceRole' but mine was 'AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup' that was giving me the same error you were getting. But after I attached a policy that had the permissions specified by 'certbot-dns-rout53', it was able to get and install a certificate.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP, but there is no "AmazonLightsailInstanceRole" listed in the IAM roles. Nor is there AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSeutp.

Answer (score -2):

After a quick check, I was able to find the following article:

https://certbot-dns-route53.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Have a look at it, it might help you to set the necessary policy.

Of course, if using AWS is not a must, you can always just deploy the website to another provider where there would not be necessary to set up policies and everything will get through just fine.